# Compare value in a 2d array to nearby values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for a way to compare each value in a 2D array to values surrounding it and returning which values are close to the value of interest (within a threshold).

The ways I've explored involve iterating through each element of a 2D array, but I feel this is not the fastest or optimal way to do it.

The input would be a 2D array (size: i x j), and the output would be two 3D arrays (k x i x j) where the "extra" dimension is there to store the i and j indices of the nearby elements that are within a threshold.

Some code to illustrate what I am doing at the moment:

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

np.random.seed(seed=10)
arr = np.random.random((100, 100))  # Some 2D input array
threshold = 0.5

# Arrays for the row and col indices
i_all, j_all = np.mgrid[0:arr.shape[0],
                        0:arr.shape[1]]  

# Footprint around the current element (ie looking at the 8 elements around the central value). Must be odd.
footprint = (3, 3)  
footprint_size = np.product(footprint)

# Prepare output for i and j indices
output_i = np.full((footprint_size, *arr.shape), np.nan)  
output_j = np.full((footprint_size, *arr.shape), np.nan)

for p, element in enumerate(tqdm(arr.flatten())):  # Iterate through each element

    i, j = np.unravel_index(p, arr.shape)

    # Create mask of elements to compare to
    mask = ((i_all >= (i - (footprint[0] - 1) / 2)) & 
            (i_all <= (i + (footprint[0] - 1) / 2)) & 
            (j_all >= (j - (footprint[1] - 1) / 2)) & 
            (j_all <= (j + (footprint[1] - 1) / 2)))

    # Create mask of those within the threshold
    close_mask = abs(arr[mask] - element) <= threshold

    if np.nansum(close_mask) < np.product(footprint):  # If at edges need to pad to be able to index into output arrays
        output_i[:, i, j] = np.pad(i_all[mask][close_mask].flatten().astype(float),
                                   (int(footprint_size - np.nansum(close_mask)), 0),
                                   mode='constant', constant_values=np.nan)
        output_j[:, i, j] = np.pad(j_all[mask][close_mask].flatten().astype(float),
                                   (int(footprint_size - np.nansum(close_mask)), 0),
                                   mode='constant', constant_values=np.nan)
    
    else:  # Don't need to pad here
        output_i[:, i, j] = i_all[mask][close_mask]
        output_j[:, i, j] = j_all[mask][close_mask]

# Output: two 3D arrays of indices corresponding to elements within the threshold of the element of interest for rows and cols
```

Which works fine for small arrays but is very slow when arrays have ~10^6 elements. The other idea I had was sliding the array over itself to compare values. This might be faster but I'm curious if there are any other ideas or built-in functions that can do a similar thing.

Comment: One way or another you'll be iterating through each element of the array. Post the code of the method you've explored and point out what you don't like about it or why it doesn't work to get a more detailed answer.

Comment: I've edited to add some code to illustrate what I'm doing at the moment.

Comment: does your output have to be in specified format? Maybe it would be easier to have 8x100x100 matrix with just True/False (is close / is not close) for each neighbour

Comment: @dankal444 Yes it might, although I guess that would require information on the search window size to also be stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know where, but I am prette sure your method has some bug. When you look at results, last (100x100) subarrays have all indices present.

What I wrote gives results that look better, is ~1000x faster, but still requires some testing from you. I might have made some error.

```
def faster_method(arr, threshold, footprint):

    temp_arr = np.full((arr.shape[0] + footprint[0] - 1, arr.shape[1] + footprint[1] - 1), np.nan)
    temp_arr[footprint[0] // 2: footprint[0] // 2 + arr.shape[0],
             footprint[1] // 2: footprint[1] // 2 + arr.shape[1]] = arr
    temp_i_all, temp_j_all = np.mgrid[-(footprint[0] // 2): arr.shape[0] + footprint[0] // 2,
                            -(footprint[1] // 2): arr.shape[1] + footprint[1] // 2]

    footprint_size = np.product(footprint)

    output_i = np.full((footprint_size, *arr.shape), np.nan)
    output_j = np.full((footprint_size, *arr.shape), np.nan)

    output_idx = 0
    for neighbour_vertical_position in range(footprint[0]):
        for neighbour_horizontal_position in range(footprint[0]):
            if neighbour_vertical_position == footprint[0] // 2 and neighbour_horizontal_position == footprint[1] // 2:
                # center point, not a neighbour, so we can keep np.nan for it everywhere
                continue
            current_neighbour = temp_arr[neighbour_horizontal_position: neighbour_horizontal_position + arr.shape[0],
                                         neighbour_vertical_position: neighbour_vertical_position + arr.shape[1]]
            current_i_all = temp_i_all[neighbour_horizontal_position: neighbour_horizontal_position + arr.shape[0],
                                       neighbour_vertical_position: neighbour_vertical_position + arr.shape[1]]
            current_j_all = temp_j_all[neighbour_horizontal_position: neighbour_horizontal_position + arr.shape[0],
                                       neighbour_vertical_position: neighbour_vertical_position + arr.shape[1]]
            is_close_array = np.abs(arr - current_neighbour) > threshold
            output_i[output_idx] = current_i_all + 0 / is_close_array
            output_j[output_idx] = current_j_all + 0 / is_close_array

    return output_i, output_j
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for some reason, it gave nan values as the output. I really like the idea though & I managed to get a similar version working which ill put below

Comment: @jeoc NaNs was default value in your example, so I decided to stick to it... Not fair to basically do the same and post it as your own answer :(

Comment: Yeah I get that it was the default value for those that aren't close, but I get almost all nan values from your code and I'm not sure why. I posted my answer of what I did using your code as I get the output I wanted. I'm happy to accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Using dankal444's answer I managed to get this working:

```
def slidingCompare(arr, footprint=(3, 3), threshold=0.5):
    """
          arr: 2D array | input
    footprint: tuple      | search window dimensions (must be odd)
    threshold: float      | Threshold for neighbours to be close
    """
    import numpy as np

    assert footprint[0] % 2 == 1, "Footprint dimensions should be odd. "
    assert footprint[0] % 2 == 1, "Footprint dimensions should be odd. "
    
    temp_arr = np.full((arr.shape[0] + footprint[0] - 1, 
                        arr.shape[1] + footprint[1] - 1), np.nan)
    temp_arr[footprint[0] // 2:footprint[0] // 2 + arr.shape[0],
             footprint[1] // 2:footprint[1] // 2 + arr.shape[1]] = arr
    
    # Arrays for the row and col indices
    i_all, j_all = np.mgrid[-(footprint[0] // 2):arr.shape[0]+(footprint[0] // 2), 
                            -(footprint[1] // 2):arr.shape[1]+(footprint[1] // 2)]

    # Footprint around the current element (ie looking at the 8 elements around the central value). Must be odd.
    footprint_size = np.product(footprint)

    # Prepare output for i and j indices
    output_i = np.full((footprint_size, *arr.shape), np.nan)
    output_j = np.full((footprint_size, *arr.shape), np.nan)

    output_ix = np.arange(footprint_size).reshape(footprint)
    
    for vert_pos in np.arange(footprint[0]):
        for horiz_pos in np.arange(footprint[1]):
            neighbour = temp_arr[vert_pos: vert_pos + arr.shape[0], 
                                 horiz_pos: horiz_pos + arr.shape[1]]
            close_mask = abs(arr - neighbour) <= threshold
            
            output_i[output_ix[vert_pos, horiz_pos], close_mask] = i_all[vert_pos: vert_pos + arr.shape[0], 
                                                    horiz_pos: horiz_pos + arr.shape[1]][close_mask]
            output_j[output_ix[vert_pos, horiz_pos], close_mask] = j_all[vert_pos: vert_pos + arr.shape[0], 
                                                    horiz_pos: horiz_pos + arr.shape[1]][close_mask]
            
    # Output: two 3D arrays of indices corresponding to elements within the threshold of the element of interest for rows and cols
    return output_i, output_j
```